# What does square brackets operator do in HLSL

Tags: shader, hlsl, hlsl2glsl

I'm working on porting our application from Windows to Linux and I need to understand what does operator [] do in HLSL and how to port in to GLSL.

I have code like this:

```c
red = texture.Sample(sampler, uv)[x];
```

Sample function should return a pixel value, right? Is x a kind of offset?

Answer (score 2):

[]-operator is the [array member selection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-operators#array-operator) and can also be used to access a vector.

The equivalent glsl code to

> ```
> red = texture.Sample(sampler, uv)[x];
> ```

is

```c
float red = texture(sampler, uv)[x];
```

`texture` returns a value of type `vec4` (e.g. for `sampler2D`). The components of the vector can be accessed by the index operator. Since `x` is the index, it has to be a variable or constant with an integral data type. The vector has 4 components (`.x`, `.y`, `.z`, `.w` respectively `.r`, `.g`, `.b`, `.a`), so the value of `x` has to be 0, 1, 2 or 3.
`texture(sampler, uv)[0]` is the same as `texture(sampler, uv).r`. See also [GLSL- Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling).